# ng-model does not get set in Internet Explorer but works in Chrome and FireFox when used in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
  <div class="input-group">
            <select class="form-control somecustomclassdefindinLESSfile" ng-   model="question.qaID">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="{{answer.qaID}}" ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">{{ answer.text }}</option>
            </select>             
        </div>
```

The above code is defined in custom directive which gets loaded multiple times.

**Issues is** :
in IE , `ng-model="question.qaID"` gets called only once , so if there are multiple combo boxes on the form , only first value gets saved , in Chrome and Firefox it works perfect

I tried below option
`ng-repeat="answer in question.answers track by answer.qaID"` but didnt help

Also tried to set the model explicitly in `ng-change` event but didnt help.

Comment: try changing ngModel to `ng-model="question[qaID]"`, bind selected answer to the value contained in `qaId` rather than to variable named `qaId`

Comment: <customdirective data-question="question" ></customdirective>

Comment: question is getting passed from custom directive